# Разделить список на словарь

Tags: python, список, словарь

Есть список:

```
['Tim: 350', 'Jane: 200', 'Alex: 400']
```

Как сделать из него такого рода словарь?:

```
{"Tim": 350, "Jane": 200, "Alex": 400}
```

Указанный список - не полный. На деле он больше, но меньше 100 строк.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще - изучите язык python, эта задача решается базовыми функциями. Изучите метод split, циклы.

```
x = ['Tim: 350', 'Jane: 200', 'Alex: 400']
z = {a.split()[0]:int(a.split()[1]) for a in x}
```

Comment: Двоеточия везде остались.

Answer (score 3):

Крохотная функция `parse` преобразует строку `'Tim: 350'` в пару `('Tim', 350)`:

```
def parse(s):
    k, v = s.split(': ')
    return k, int(v)
```

Напускаем её на список строк. Получается (не) список пар `('Tim', 350), ('Jane', 200), ('Alex', 400)`. Его передаём в конструктор `dict`:

```
lst = ['Tim: 350', 'Jane: 200', 'Alex: 400']
d = dict(map(parse, lst))
print(d)
```

> ```
> {'Tim': 350, 'Jane': 200, 'Alex': 400}
> ```

Comment: можно извратиться и в 1 строчку - `d = dict(map(lambda s: (v := s.split(': '), (v[0], int(v[1])))[1], lst))`

Comment: @Zhihar, можно. Не люблю побочные эффекты в выражениях. В частности, не люблю `:=`.

Comment: @Zhihar, самоприменяющаяся лямбда вместо `:=`: `d = dict(map(lambda s: (lambda k, v: (k, int(v)))(*s.split(': ')), lst))`.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = ['Tim: 350', 'Jane: 200', 'Alex: 400']
```

**вариант 1:**

```
res = dict((a := v.split(), (a[0][:-1], int(a[1])))[1] for v in arr)
```

**вариант 2:**

```
res = {a[:-1]:int(b) for a, b in map(str.split, arr)}
```

**вариант 2.1** (понадёжнее, если в строке может быть несколько компонент:

```
res = {v[0][:-1]:int(v[1]) for v in map(str.split, arr)}
```

**вариант 3: изврат без `for`**

```
res = dict(zip(list(zip(*map(str.split, arr)))[0], map(int, list(zip(*map(str.split, arr)))[1])))
```

Comment: ой - не заметил, что их убрать надо :), подправил